# d3 parsing and drawing nested csv data

Tags: csv, d3.js

I am a d3 noob trying to create a bar chart using data like the following:

```
date, fruit, qty
1/1/14, apple, 10
1/1/14, orange, 0
1/1/14, banana, 20
1/2/14, apple, 12
1/2/14, orange, 5
1/2/14, banana, 30    
1/3/14, apple, 16
1/3/14, orange, 15
1/3/14, banana, 40
```

In this bar chart each fruit would have a bar that would grow to the height of `qty` at the rate of, let's say, 1 second (realtime) per day (or row of the csv). I'm not trying to update on-click, or any other interaction.  I would like the bars to grow automatically.

I am easily able to render a bar chart using static data, but I am struggling with parsing and cycling through the data.  I referenced [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1256572), but it is a little over my head.

I'm trying to parse the csv using this code:

```
    var fruits;

    d3.csv("faux_data.csv", function(error, data) {
        var parse = d3.time.format("%m-%d-%y").parse;

        exams = d3.nest()
                 .key(function(d) {return d.fruit; })
                 .entries(fruits = data);

        exams.forEach(function(s) {
            s.values
             .forEach(function(d) { d.date = parse (d.date); d.qty = + d.qty; } );
        });

    });
```

And then I am at a loss as to how to move through this updating the rect svgs I was creating using this code:

```
    var svgContainer = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", 400)
                        .attr("height", 300);

    var rectangles = svgContainer.selectAll("rect")
                        .data(fruits)
                        .enter()
                        .append("rect");

    var rectangleAttributes = rectangles
                        .attr("x", function (d, i) { return (i * 55);})
                        .attr("y", function(d) { return (250 - d.qty);})
                        .attr("width", 50)
                        .attr("height", function(d) {return d.qty;});
```

Any tips or clear explanations (aimed at the noob level) as to how d3 and js deal with csv data would be much appreciated.

Comment: Everything you need to know about this is covered in [General Update Pattern](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218). There are parts 2 and 3 as well. See links at end of paragraph.

Comment: The General Update Pattern stuff is helpful, but it doesn't get me past the confusion of how to get d3 to advance through a nested csv.  This is likely related to my paltry js knowledge.  Can you give me any more info on this?

Answer (score 0):

Your goal should be to use a `setTimeout` loop to repeatedly call a function that updates `fruits` (or `exams`) and then updates the view as outlined in the General Update Pattern. Something like

```
d3.csv("faux_data.csv", function(error, data) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    fruits = ... // re-nest all the data
    updateView() // render view based on the current values of fruits
  }, 500)
});
```

I think you can figure out how to implement `updateView()` following the recommendation of General Update Pattern. The remaining challenge is how to prepare `fruits`.

First, the thing you're doing with the `.forEach` loops can be achieved using the `.rollup()` function of `d3.nest`. It's not mandatory, but it's cleaner. (Note that you have a bug with `d.qty = + d.qty`, which probably wants to become `d.qty += d.qty`).

Here's how it would look with `.rollup()` — assuming I didn't miss anything, since I haven't tried it in a console....

```
fruits = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) {return d.fruit; })
  .entries(fruits = data);
  .rollup(function(values) {
    return d3.sum(values, function(d) {
      return d.qty;
    });
  });
```

This will sum up all the quantities per fruit across ALL TIME. However, since you're looking to advance through time incrementally, you need to introduce some limits on how much should get summed per iteration of `setTimeout`. It's up to you how to define the limiting criteria, but here are a couple of ideas:

```
  // This sums up the first 5 elements of each fruit.
  // Instead of hard-coding the 5, you can set and
  // increment a variable at each iteration
  .rollup(function(values) {
    return d3.sum(values.slice(0, 5), function(d) {
      return d.qty;
    });
  });
```

or

```
  // This sums up per fruit all values PRIOR to Jan, 1st 2015.
  // Instead of hard-coding the date, you can set and increment
  // a Date variable at each iteration
  .rollup(function(values) {
    return d3.sum(values, function(d) {
      if(Number(d) < Number(new Date(2015, 0, 1)))
        return d.qty;
      else
        return 0;
    });
  });
```

Using `d3.sum` implies that JavaScript is looping through all the data per iteration. There are other ways to set it up such that it's not looping through all that, since actually all that's needed is adding a new `d.qty` to a previously computed sum of older `d.qty`. But unless your dataset is humungous it's not a huge issue and probably not worth worrying about. And anyway, it's better to optimize AFTER you figure out how to do it the naive way. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @meetamit, I will try this out tonight and see if I can get it to run.  Additional thanks for the bug-catch!